# if else in FindAll using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl this ip address using bs4. Here, the ip is 103.18.75.62

```
<div class="the-ip"><label id="a829266">1</label><label id="a814974">0</label><span id="a968168">3</span><label id="d735847">.</label><span id="d111988">1</span><span id="b284407">8</span><span id="b740896">.</span><label id="d817182">7</label><label id="e268019">5</label><span id="a721115">.</span><label id="e816439">6</label><span id="b903319">2</span></div>
```

I was expecting something like the following to work

```
ip_div = soup.findAll('div' , class_ ='the-ip')
ips = ip[0].findAll('label' AND 'span')   // how to implement this AND ???
for i in ips:
    print i.get_text()
```

So how to implement this AND ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) with `div.the-ip *` as css selector:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <div class="the-ip">
...     <label id="a829266">1</label>
...     <label id="a814974">0</label>
...     <span id="a968168">3</span>
...     <label id="d735847">.</label>
...     <span id="d111988">1</span>
...     <span id="b284407">8</span>
...     <span id="b740896">.</span>
...     <label id="d817182">7</label>
...     <label id="e268019">5</label>
...     <span id="a721115">.</span>
...     <label id="e816439">6</label>
...     <span id="b903319">2</span>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> ''.join(el.text for el in soup.select('div.the-ip *'))
u'103.18.75.62'
```

I thought `div.the-ip>*` (or `div.the-ip>label, div.the-ip>span`) should work, too. But that's does not work with bs4. (works with lxml)

### Answer to the question `how to implement this AND`?

Do you mean **OR**?

You can pass a compiled regular expression pattern instead of a string:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> ip_div = soup.find('div' , class_='the-ip') # `find`, not `findAll` here.
>>> ''.join(el.text for el in ip_div.findAll(re.compile('^(label|span)$')))
u'103.18.75.62'
```

`^(label|span)$` matches `label` or `span`.

Comment: Works like charm... but i still wonder if there's a way to implement "AND" in FindAll

Comment: @suneet, I see. You mean **OR**? I updated the answer.

Comment: oops. yes OR... PERFECT ANSWER :*